Why does Visual Studio Code keep failing and retrying when connecting to a remote server?
Visual Studio Code keeps failing and retrying to connect to the server, and the issue persists even after trying multiple versions of VSCode. ERROR: WebSocket close with status code 1006
error messages
how to deal with this problem
